# Waze crashes immediately on startup

Tags: iphone, applications

When trying to enter Waze from iphone 10 the app immediately closes itself. I tried uninstalling it and rebooting but that didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: I also tried deleting it from the settings, didn't help :/

Comment: What iOS version are you on?  What version of Waze?  Did Waze ever work for you?  If so, what changed since that time?  You need to give us more info, we're not looking over your shoulder when you run the app.

Comment: it worked before, don't know what has changed. IOS 13.5.1 and waze version 4.64 (latest one)

Comment: The same thing happens to me with that Waze version.  That version came out a week ago and that's just about when I noticed it last worked. I think it's a bug in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Waze](https://www.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=303610&sid=f9d01662ad9a11439d402a400cf8b420), this is a known bug with this version.

Waze is reporting it as "a Facebook issue" and directing users to [this Facebook developer URL](https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/1739188102911114/) for more info.

Also, there's a [megathread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/homx7a/facebook_sdk_causing_app_crashes_megathread/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf) with a list of apps that are impacted by this Facebook SDK issue.  You don't have to have Facebook installed or have a Facebook account for this bug to impact your apps.  If the app uses a Facebook library, it will be affected.

**Updated**: There a workaround for this issue as posted in a [Verge article](https://www.theverge.com/21319817/facebook-ios-sdk-bug-fix-spotify-pinterest-tinder-crash-iphone-ios):

> Lockdown Apps, a firewall and privacy protection app on iOS, uses a VPN to block trackers and things like Facebook’s iOS SDK from loading in third-party apps. It will allow apps like Spotify, Pinterest, and Tinder to launch during a Facebook iOS SDK outage, and it’s completely free to use.

I've tried this using the Lockdown app and I'm able to launch Waze without a problem.

Comment: Problem is now solved (for everyone I believe)